# Decomposing uint32s into uint8s in a large matrix

Tags: image, matlab, matrix

For a project I am working on,  I am loading in large image files, which Matlab inputs as LxWx3 arrays of uint8s. I have a function which concatenates these component-wise into a LxWx1 array of uint32s,  but I can't find a way to do the reverse without using nested for loops, which is far too slow for the matrices I am working with.

Could anyone recommend a way to accomplish this effuciently? Basically, given a LxW Matrix of uint32s,  I want to return a LxWx3 matrix of uint8s,  where the (x, y,1:3) components are the three most significant bytes in the corresponding uint32.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with [`typecast`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/typecast.html):

```
A = uint32([2^16 2^30; 256 513]);
B = permute(reshape(typecast(A(:), 'uint8'), [], size(A,1), size(A,2)), [2 3 1]);
B = flipdim(B, 3); %// flip 3rd dim to bring MSB first, if needed (depends on computer)
B = B(:,:,2:4);
```

Example: for `A = uint32([2^16 2^30; 256 513]);`

```
A =
       65536  1073741824
         256         513
```

the result is

```
B(:,:,1) =
    1    0
    0    0
B(:,:,2) =
    0    0
    1    2
B(:,:,3) =
    0    0
    0    1
```

Comment: Glad it works for you. It sould be pretty fast, because it (probably) doesn't involve arithmetic operations